# (Node js) received a SyntaxError while install google-cloud/discoveryengine

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

while npm install @google-cloud/discoveryengine completed

i got a SyntaxError as below:

[image]

path as :node_modules/@google-cloud/discoveryengine/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/index.js:54

Has anyone else encountered the same issue as me? and how to correctly to solved this problem?

I would appreciate it if everyone could offer me some advice. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall dependencies
Remove the `node_modules` directory and the `package-lock.json` file, then reinstall the dependencies

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json 
npm install
```

Also check your node version is compatible with the dependencies or not.

Happy coding!